# Export latitude/longitude coordinates of a R map plot into an external file

Tags: r, csv, latitude-longitude, maps

I have a simple map and like to export the used coordinates of latitude/longitude
into an external CSV file. Is this possible?

```
library('maps')
map(database='world',regions='germany')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (invisible) return value of `map` is a list with `x`, `y`, `range`, and `names` components (See *Value* section in the manual page, i.e. `?map`):

```
dat <- map(database="world",regions = "germany", plot = FALSE)
str(dat)
# List of 4
#  $ x    : num [1:596] 14.2 14.2 14 13.9 13.9 ...
#  $ y    : num [1:596] 53.9 53.9 53.9 53.9 53.9 ...
#  $ range: num [1:4] 5.86 15.02 47.28 55.06
#  $ names: chr [1:7] "Germany:Usedom" "Germany:Fehmarn" "Germany:Rugen" "Germany:4" ...
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr "map"
write.table(data.frame(x = dat$x, y = dat$y), "germany.csv")
```